# How to edit the live boot files and customize it permanently?

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-kernel

So the boot files for the OS are stored in the `/cdrom` directory.

I want to edit that OS and configure it a bit. It is a live boot by the way. Is there any way i can edit those files?

It would have been easier if it was an ISO file, but it is not.

So please tell me if there is any way I can edit the OS and compile it back.

I mean edit the wallpaper, change a few applications, etc. because it is live boot, and the changes will go if i turn off the computer

Thanks In Advance!!!

Here is a picture for reference - 
[image: The Boot Files]

Comment: You'll need to be more specific about what you mean by "edit the OS."

Comment: Since it is live boot, i want to change the wallpaper, applications, etc.

Comment: OK. Those changes are not made in /boot. Which live Linux distro are you using?

Comment: I am using an Ubuntu linux distribution which has been configured earlier by my school. I just want to edit the live boot contents like the wallpaper and a few applications. Thanks

Comment: And by the way, i am not using an external pendrive. The live boot is stored in the internal hard disc.